# Friedmann Equation with imaginary values

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, complex-numbers

Consider the Friedmann equation with no radiation:

$$
\frac{H(t)^2}{H_0^2} = \Omega_{m,0} a^{-3} + \Omega_{k,0} a^{-2} + \Omega_{\Lambda,0}
$$

We can have values for $a(t)$ and the density parameters such as the right hand side of the equation is negative. That would imply an imaginary Hubble constant. Is there any physical interpretation for that?

Comment: What term(s) on the right hand side are you expecting to be negative?

Comment: Using just mathematics without caring much $\tilde{S}\doteq S/\sqrt{|K|}, H(t)\doteq \dot{\tilde{S}}/\tilde{S}$ so if $H(t)=\pm i \alpha(t)$ that would mean $\ln{|\tilde{S}|}=\pm i\int \text{d}t\alpha(t)$. Am I wrong? Seems like an obscillating omogeneus universe. But at the same time I don't know if actually having imaginary Hubble parameter is possible, or if there is some mathematical/physical impediment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to interpret Friedmann equation with an imaginary Hubble parameter is as arising from some  solution with *Euclidean* metric signature. One class of such solution, termed “Euclidean wormholes” consists of two large asymptotic regions connected by a “throat”. Many FLRW cosmologies analytically continued into an [imaginary time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_time) become such Euclidean wormholes.

- Zhuk, A. (1993). *Perfect fluid wormholes*. Physics Letters A, 176(3-4), 176-178, [doi:10.1016/0375-9601(93)91030-9](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0375-9601(93)91030-9), [free pdf](https://www.academia.edu/31167263/Perfect_fluid_wormholes).

Abstract:

> It  is shown that most important closed Robertson–Walker–Friedmann universe models with a perfect fluid have ananalytic continuation into the Euclidean region with a wormhole-type topology.

Answer (score 2):

There is a close analogy:

If you jump say 3 feet high, you can calculate your speed as a function of you position between 0 to 3 feet high.

Then you wonder what is your speed at 6 feet high during your jump. The good old high school Newtonian mechanics offers an answer: your speed was imaginary at 6 feet high according to the total energy conservation equation.

Now it is your turn to tell me what is the epistemologically transcendent metaphysical interpretation of that.